# What's the best soil for filling around the building walls?

Tags: walls, foundation, building, soil, filling

The ground is made of clay so we excavated and did the back filling with river sand and we have laid the excavated clay around the building walls.
But I'm noticing that rain water that runs off from the building wall to ground.

I'm noticing many of the buildings have river sand filling around the building.

But is clay not a ideal choice - because absorption rate is less and it would be good for building foundation and wall?

**Update**

Please find some images and videos around the building.

[image]

[image]

[View south side of the building video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tHSitIxg8Rcq8tgbv7tGf5qFfSfxhgqq/view)

[View north side of the building video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mITg0oWOYoWc6zaZzsQLR5ARbxEZ4W2l/view)

Comment: river sand is better than clay

Comment: Are you asking about the soil the footings rest on, or about the soil that's back filled against the foundation/basement walls?

Comment: @SteveSh it's a clay area. so we have filled the bottom of footing with sand and did a backfilling for foundation and basewment walls with sand as well. the area that surrounds the building has clay.. so I'm just wondering would it be right to excavate the clay and fill it with sand or some other sand ?

Comment: @Ruskes - I have one doubt. If I use river sand wouldn't it abosrb lots of water and impact the foundation ?

Comment: @Amogam - Sand (and gravel) in general is considered a good material on which to build footings.  Clay is the worse.  This is based on load carrying capability, psi or pounds per square foot.  Clay also emulsifies or liquifies when it gets wet and so can flow or ooze.

Comment: Pics are you friend here.  Do you have any kind of underdrain for your river sand?  Where is the water supposed to go once it gets in the sand?  Do you have a roof overhang?  Do you have gutters and downspouts?

Comment: @Huesmann - The rain water from the terrace is captured in PVC pipe and led far away from the building , My building is 60 ft by 30 ft,, one side of 60 feet has concrete overhang stair case to reach to the terrace in second floor.  and other side of 60 feet doesn't have any types of overhang and my question about filing the river sand or let the clay sand be there comes for this side only

Comment: @SteveSh - The building is sitting on top of sand backfilling. So I'm wondering should I fill the sides of building wall with sand or just let it have clay as it is

Comment: @Huesmann - I've updated my question with pics and videos

Comment: In some respects, clay is an ideal surface material because it doesn't absorb water quickly.  But, it swells when it absorbs (probably something to do with relative particle size and water tension) which is bad against a foundation, and it drains slowly.

Comment: makes sense thanks